# Accessing jasper reports through the web

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

i know that this is a trivial question but this is the best place to ask it. I have a database which is hosted on a website. I have written a Java program that accesses the database and through this program the user can view reports. I used Jasper Reports for this. Now i have a website where the user can log in and would like the user to be able to view the exact same reports but through my website. In other words, what is the equivalent of Jasper Reports for a web page? I know that there is something called JasperReports Server but Im not sure if that is what i am looking for and how is it possible to incorporate into into my html/php site. Can someone please direct me to the right place? Thanks.

Comment: Still not clear what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to use the same jrxml files which I created for the Java program to allow the user to view the same reports through a website.

Comment: You can do that with jasper report, you might not need jasper server. Look into tutorials for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display Jasper reports using any of the following approaches:

- Publish JRXML reports into Jasper server and embed Jasper server into your application using IFrame.
- Publish JRXML reports into Jasper server and call those reports in your application using Soap or Restful web services.
- Use Jasper API to display jasper reports directly in your application. Refer Jasper reports for Java tutorials for more info.

Thanks,

Srikanth Kattam

Comment: Thanks. I will look into these options.